# Dagger 2 Scopes, where to place Presenters?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-mvp

what would it be the best practice about placing Presenters in a Scope?

Could we have Presenters on @Singleton or @AppScope without any problem?

Should they be placed in an @ActivityScope in order to destroy them each time the activity is destroyed?

Comment: I just wrote a similar answer the other day about keeping presenters and problems how that plays with scopes, you might want to have a look there https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398997/1837367

Comment: Really well explained answer.  I currently facing a project which has Presenters on @Singleton scope and I personally don't like it. That' why I was asking this question. Just another question, when we have Scopes, are all the providers of that scope  initialized when the scope is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what would it be the best practice about placing Presenters in a Scope?

Usually a presenter should be in *some* scope. Not placing it in any scope will lead to problems, as every time you request a presenter it would create a new one.

*Which* scope you choose mostly depends on your programming style, but the most common would probably be `@PerActivity`, as a scope that follows the lifecycle of the Activity. (the same way you can use something like `@PerFragment` with Fragments and their lifecycle)

> Could we have Presenters on @Singleton or @AppScope without any problem?

Yes and no. Longer living objects referencing shorter lived ones (e.g. a `@Singleton` object that references an activity-lifecycled one) usually is not a good practice that might lead to memory leaks.

You can avoid these issues by properly adding / removing your shorter lived objects (e.g. add in `onCreate`, remove in `onDestroy`) or using `WeakReference`.

Some programmers will keep their presenters as `@Singleton` or in some similar fashion and swap views, but again this depends on how you prefer your code. It will work, but you must make sure what objects you reference and to clean up afterwards.

> Should they be placed in an @ActivityScope in order to destroy them each time the activity is destroyed?

This is by far the easiest option, since you have no problem referencing the Activity or anything else that depends on it. You most likely won't have to worry about memory leaks or other issues this way.

---

In the end its *your* code and you have to do what works best for *you*.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I have always worked with @ActivityScope approach that's why I had doubts about having all presenters on the same scope.