# remove references from memory

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm using [dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger) for **dependency injection** in my **android** app project.

and the question is how to remove references from component when the activity dies ?

I've read some documents about custom **scopes** and i've created a custom scope called **@ForActivity**, so references that have this annotation on them will remove when activity dies, but they don't.

any suggestions on this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your component shares the lifecycle of the Activity—that means create the component in `onCreate`, store it in the Activity itself—it will be garbage collected along with the Activity at the end of the Activities lifetime.

If on the other hand you put a component that references the Activity in some way in a static variable, or some other longer lived object, you will create a memory leak. This is the only thing to keep in mind.

Nothing will be magically "removed" since Dagger just generates POJOs that handle object creation for you. Usually it is enough to just let the GC do its job.

Scopes just group dependencies and define relationships, but in the end your component is just an object that holds more objects. The Garbage Collector will remove it along with the Activity and everything else if you don't create memory leaks as mentioned above.

---

I recently also gave 2 detailed answers about scopes / activities / scoped objects, where you find more concrete examples on how to work with scopes / activites:

- [Dagger 2 Scopes, where to place Presenters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444044/1837367)
- [Dagger 2 with MVP, avoid creating extra presenter object on view recreation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398997/1837367)